# Error in class method when implementing Core Data Stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, class-method

I followed [this](https://medium.com/soundwave-stories/core-data-cffe22efe716#.hry7pg876) tutorial to implement my Core Data Stack and I'm getting an error in the temporaryWorkerContext class method.

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)temporaryWorkerContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *tempMOContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    tempMOContext.parentContext = _mainManagedObjectContext;<--Error here: Instance variable '_mainManagedObjectContext' accessed in class method
    return tempMOContext;
}
```

My question is, what is the correct way to implement the core data stack without any errors? The class method is required, so that my controller calling it would hold a strong reference to the temporaryWorkerContext.

Comment: The first question is: does one of `_mainManagedObjectContext` need to exist for each instance of this class or is there only supposed to be one in total?

Comment: @PhillipMills There should only be one _mainManagedObjectContext total. The workerManagedObjectContext class method is supposed to create a temporary context and have _mainManagedObjectContext as its parent.

Comment: If that's true, then make it a static variable instead of an instance variable.